# Buddypress Plugin for register user from other site's

Tags: plugins, buddypress, user-registration

Buddypress plugin which register user from other social sites like...Facebook, twitter and also from google.

I think there is one buddypress exist only for facebook but not for others.. any one know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot fully understand your question,
 
But i think you need a plugin to make users register through their facebook, google, twitter id.
If thats the case use [janrain engage](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rpx/) plugin.

Comment: Hi @Ezhil, You are right i want a plugin which allow user from other social sites to register on my site.... and is this plugin install with buddypress.

Comment: I think it would do so.

Comment: I test it on buddypress, which show icons only in admin login side, and doesn't show any icon on buddypress front-end login or registration page....